# asp:treeView hiding the /- button?

Tags: asp.net

I have a treeView in an app I'm making. I changed the parent nodes to expand when clicked using the SelectAction propery, so now I'd like to remove the +/- expansion button. However I tried setting navTree.ShowExpandCollapse = false; but this disabled the expansion ability of my parent nodes.

Does anyone now how to remove the +/- button without messing up my node's select action event?

thanks

Here's my CS

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Service1 myService = new Service1();


      //  //Populate the site menu
        GridView sites = new GridView();


        sites.DataSource = myService.GetAllSites();
        sites.DataBind();


        foreach (GridViewRow siteRow in sites.Rows) {
            TreeNode ParentNode = new TreeNode(siteRow.Cells[1].Text);
            ParentNode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Expand;
            ParentNode.Collapse();
            navTree.Nodes.Add(ParentNode);


            TreeNode ChildNode = new TreeNode(siteRow.Cells[2].Text);
            ChildNode.NavigateUrl = "http://ign.com";
            ParentNode.ChildNodes.Add(ChildNode);

        } 


    }
```

Here's my aspx file

```
            <asp:TreeView ID="navTree" runat="server" NodeIndent="0" >  
                <Nodes>
                <asp:TreeNode Value="Parent1" Expanded="True" Text="1">
                <asp:TreeNode Value="Child1A" Text="A" />
                <asp:TreeNode Value="Child1B" Text="B" />
                </asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Value="Parent2" Text="2">
                </asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Value="Parent3" Expanded="True" Text="3">
                <asp:TreeNode Value="Child3A" Text="A">
                </asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
                         </Nodes>
                     </asp:TreeView>
         </div>
```

Comment: Do you have any code to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS solution:

```
<style>
#TreeView1 table td a img
{
    display:none!important;    
}
</style>
```

Where `TreeView1` is the ID of your tree. The image is still there, but not visible.

jQuery solution:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#<%=TreeView1.ClientID %> table td a img").hide();
    });
</script>
```

This actually removes the image from the DOM.

Comment: The OP should note that they'll need to use a placeholder image for your solution to work.  If they aren't currently using images, I think the Treeview just renders "+" and "-" characters as the expand/collapse target.  But this is really the simplest way to accomplish what the OP wants.

Comment: thanks, this has just about done the trick. I changed the ImageSet property of the tree to the TreeViewImageSet.Arrows; With yout code, this removed the +/- button, but now i have arrows next to my child node xD

Comment: Do you want these arrows gone as well?

Comment: Got it working just changed the expand/collapse imageURL to ""

Comment: You could probably just tweak the CSS rule to hide all images in the TreeView (unless your nodes legimitately contain images) @WillTuttle.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative solution, just assign a png blank transparent picture with 1x1 pixel size to

```
CollapseImageUrl
ExpandImageUrl
```

Comment: Simple solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add the `ShowExpandCollapse`property to your treeview control and set it to false:

```
 <asp:TreeView ID="navTree" runat="server" NodeIndent="0" ShowExpandCollapse="false">
```